# How to migrate a remote mail server without having to notify its users?

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

I've got a remote mail server(henceforth A), based on [this](https://workaround.org/ispmail/buster/) tutorial. Dovecot is the software used as the IMAP/POP3 mail server. I want to migrate every byte in A to another remote server(henceforth B), so that B will act as the mail server and I can dismantle A. The issues are that:

1. I don't want to have to notify the hundreds of users of the
   migration, because of the time-consuming trouble it'll create.
2. I would ideally like to avoid the whole "DNS worldwide update"
   thing, since it can take up to 2 days.
3. I would like to have the option to keep A as a backup server in case B has any issues that need resolving. And when everything is okay with B, I can dismantle A.

How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: Would you consider using `iptables` to route incoming mail traffic on server A to server B? If that works, you can do the DNS update without your users losing connection.

Comment: @Jos a valid answer, but wouldn't I need to set up server B as a mail server, and since it will have a different domain name, I would have to notify the users?

Comment: Yes, you would still need to setup B as a mail server and shutdown the mail server at A, but once the `iptables` rule is running, you can change the DNS setup at your leisure. Provided you are in control of DNS settings for both domains. Simply point the name A to the ip address of B. For users using the old IP address of A, traffic will be redirected to B by `iptables` until they have received the DNS change.

Comment: That's a nice idea. However, the issue is that I can't really notify the users, as it would cause troubles for everyone involved, mostly them. I will keep the tip you provided, though, as it's a nice one.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I deleted my suggestion where you still need to notify the users, and added another where you don't.

Comment: So, what you're suggesting: Set up server B as a mail server. put an `iptables` rule into server A and shutdown the mail server on it as well, so that all mail traffic gets rerouted to server B. At the same time, I put the same domain into server B. And, of course, put a queue up in case any emails to/from the server is being sent. Correct?

Comment: Exactly. Networkwise this should work without the users noticing anything. There may be emails sent to or from the server while you are busy migrating, but that is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

as already commented there are some Options for such a Job. I did this some years ago with a small mailserver. looking at you questions:

1. you will need to inform the users as you will need a maintenance window for data migration - or use some tools to keep the old and the new Mail server in sync.
   The amount of data and the speed between thetwo servers mainly define the time needed for migration.
2. DNS - this is already discussed in the comments, but here are my 5 cents:
   an e-Mail server require VERY proper DNS settings including forward, reverse, mx, dkim (txt) and SPF (txt) entries. you may lower the DNS TTL to increase the speed of the DNS upgrade.
   You should check th rputation of your new IP on e.g. https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx and enshure the new IP is nowere blaklisted. This was a puinfull process.
3. of course you may shutdown all Services on A and you are able to restart these. please this about data consitency in tis case. this requires some kind of Sync between the imapservers.

Off the Record: I got away from setting to individual services directly of the OS. you may have a look at container based solutions like https://mailcow.email/